# Blackberry google plus

Tags: blackberry, google-plus

I want to integrate Google+ into my blackberry application i have implemented Google+ by means of invoking browser session,once user login the G+ account from my application i want to take their e-mail,user-id, How to do this,can anyone give me solution,i got stuck in this.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look out for blackberry google + integration https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login,
By registering your app by using app id you can connect.
refer this link also 
 https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2Draft10

Comment: Can you explain brief

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OAuth 2.0 for Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) to retrieve their user-id and email after they have authenticated on a Google Authorization Server and have given their consent to your app to access those info.